# Swift: How to Append to an NSObject Array?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, core-data, swift, nsobject

I researched StackOverflow and Google, and reviewed most StackOverflow Swift examples, but the solution to my issue is still elusive. I have CoreData with a userName and userAge that I need to display in a TableView. I understand I need to use a class with objects, then refer to the object name and age in the cell configuration.

My custom class is defined as:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var userName: String
    var userAge: Int
    init(userName: String, userAge: Int) {
        self.userName = userName
        self.userAge = userAge
        super.init()
    }
}
```

In the TableView controller:

```
var users: [User] = []
```

followed by logic to retrieve users records from Core Data model; then for each record retrieved:

```
let userDataObject = [ User(userName: userNameFromCoreData!, userAge: userAgeFromCoreData!)]
```

the problem is when I try to append each user record to the array so I can then show the array in the table:

```
users.append(userDataObject)
```

gives a Swift Compiler Error '**NSArray' is not a subtype of 'User'.**

If I use

```
var users: [AnyObject] = []
```

the users.append(userDataObject) works, but then I am not sure how to retrieve the user name and age from the array.

I tried appending the entity Class field as appName.User (where appName is the real application name) but the users.append still failed with same error.

I am aware this is a downcasting issue, of some sort, and feel it could be just syntax in the code above, but would be most grateful for your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you Leonardo for the Class code edit. Lesson learnt for next question/reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the User object into an array?

Instead of this:

```
let userDataObject = [ User(userName: userNameFromCoreData!, userAge: userAgeFromCoreData!)]
users.append(userDataObject)
```

Do this:

```
let userDataObject = User(userName: userNameFromCoreData!, userAge: userAgeFromCoreData!)
users.append(userDataObject)
```

---

If you really want to append an array (e.g. because it contains multiple objects) you can use the `+` operator

```
users += userDataObjects
```

Comment: Thank You, Matthias. It worked fine. Now that you pointed it out, it makes perfect sense (but I did  miss it). Thanks again.